# Why do font size commands like \large have to be wrapped in blocks as opposed to e.g. \textbf?

Tags: fonts

This is probably a beginner question, but it's always been throwing me off about LaTeX, especially because when I'm showing new people the basics, I can't explain why that is.

So the question is: Why does `\large` have to be wrapped inside `{}` to not make everything after it become large as well? When I type `\large{Some text}` it doesn't mean at all what one might expect (`{Some text}` isn't an argument apparently). For commands like `\textbf` it works the way I'm used to for most commands: Without braces, it just affects the next token, with curlies, it affects that whole argument inside the curlies *and nothing beyond that*.

Is there a term for these kinds of commands? I don't recall having seen very many others that behave like this.

Comment: `\large` is a font size declaration which is active until another font size declaration appears or the local group ends. In fact, `\large` does not have an argument, so `\large{foo}` is actually wrong but does not really do harm

Comment: `\textbf{...}` is just a convenience function, because you often only want to typeset a few words in bold. The command that does the work is `\bfseries` which is like `\large` stays in force until it is cancelled. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts for a longer list of similar macros.

Comment: " Without braces, it just affects the next token," - in fact, it always affects *its parameter*. If there are no curly brackets, the parameter is the next single character. If there are brackets, the parameter is everything inside the brackets. This rule applies to *all* `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` commands - it's nothing special to do with `textbf`.

Comment: Basically something like `\large` can be considered like the speed limit sign on a road: The speed limit on it usually holds until the next speed limit (either lower or higher) appears...

Comment: `\bfseries`, `\color{red}`, `\sloppy`, `\raggedright`,  `\large` are all declarations that affect all following text until the end of the current group

Comment: It's the difference between a macro that changes the state of the system and a command that takes an argument.